# Resultado erróneo al ejecutar una Operación dentro de una Función JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con JS, tengo que ingresar dos datos y de estos datos tengo que sacar el impuesto del 18% y el subtotal, ahora mismo trato de sacar el subtotal y me sale mal la operación, no tengo mucho conocimiento en JS.

**Código**

```js
function subtotal (valor) {
valor = parseInt(valor);
var total = 1;
var igv = 0.18;
total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;
total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 1 : total;
sub = (parseInt(total) * parseInt(valor))
sub2= (sub * igv);
total = (sub - sub2);
document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-5">
     <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Precio Unit.:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name1" id="txt_campo_1" onchange="subtotal(this.value);">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-5">
     <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Cantidad:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name1" id="txt_campo_2" onchange="subtotal(this.value);">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Sub Total:</label>
    <label type="text" class="" for="" id="spTotal"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">IGV (18%):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name1" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Total:</label><br>
    <label type="text" class="" for="" id="spTotal"></label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: y cual es el error que te da?

Comment: Hola Alfredo, cuando ingreso el dato por decirte 10 en precio unit. me da como resultado en sub. total 8.2 que es correcto, pero si agrego la cantidad de productos ejemplo 1 me da 6.5600000000000005 el cual es incorrecto, si no que tiene que salir 8.2, no se si me dejo entender.

Comment: Hola @MegaPattern bienvenido al sitio, al  parecer su error es lógica. ¿Cómo identifica que el valor enviado por parámetro a la función es una cantidad o es un precio unitario? debería poder identificar esto para realizar un proceso más limpio y sencillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que está re calculando el `subtotal` cuando ingresa una segunda vez a la función, es decir al momento de modificar la cantidad o el precio unitario.

Además hay problemas muy sobresalientes.

- Deberá definir un solo identificador para los campos y de preferencia que sean descriptivos.
- Si espera valores numéricos, debería usar un input de tipo `number` como primer paso de validación.
- Se está basando en el contenido de lo que arroje `innerHTML` del label, lo correcto sería acceder al `textContent`.
- Si trabaja con valores como precios, cantidades, totales  conviene utilizar `parseFloat` en lugar de `parseInt`.
- No creo que deba pasarse el mismo valor a una función con diferente significado, ya que no veo donde valide que el parámetro se trata de la cantidad o del precioUnitario. *( es aquí donde tiene errores de lógica)*
- El total se calcula como resultado final, pero usted antes de realizar las operaciones de multiplicación ya tiene asignado valores. ¿Por qué ?

  ```
  total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;
  total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 1 : total;
  ```

Código con Proceso más sencillo y limpio de entender. *(Puede mejorarlo o adaptarlo a lo que desee, utilizo toFixed para formatear los valores a 2 digitos decimales)*

```js
var igv = 0.18;
//Referencias que no cambiarán
var lblSubTotal = document.getElementById('spSubTotal');
var lblTotal = document.getElementById('spTotal');
var inputIGV = document.getElementById('totaligv');
function subtotal () {
    //Obtenemos la cantidad y el precio,si no hay valor asignamos 1 
    let cantidad = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cantidad').value) || 1;
    let precioU = parseFloat(document.getElementById('precio').value) || 1;
    //Realizamos las operaciones básicas de multiplicación y resta
    let subtotalSinIGV = cantidad * precioU;
    let totalIGV =  (subtotalSinIGV*igv);
    let subtotalConIGV = subtotalSinIGV  - totalIGV;
    //Asignamos los valores  a los labels o inputs respectivos.
    lblSubTotal.textContent = subtotalConIGV.toFixed(2);
    inputIGV.value = totalIGV.toFixed(2);
    lblTotal.textContent =subtotalSinIGV;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-5">
     <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Precio Unit.:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="precio" onchange="subtotal();">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-5">
     <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Cantidad:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" onchange="subtotal();">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Sub Total:</label>
    <label type="number"  id="spSubTotal"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">IGV (18%):</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totaligv" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Total:</label><br>
    <label type="text" class="" id="spTotal"></label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Si tienes precio unitario 10 y 10 unidades muestra un subtotal de 82, no debería ser 100? Y sobre este calcular el total con el IGV? Además de mantener el `default` en campos vacíos en 0 y no en 1, en caso que se coloque cantidad pero no precio.

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que el subtotal es `unidad * cantidad`, el impuesto es el %18 del subtotal, y para calcular el total es `1.18 * subtotal`.

El nombre de la función la cambié por `calcular`, siempre pongo nombres de verbos o acciones.

Hay que tener en cuenta que no deberían existir varios elementos con el mismo `id`, es decir, que todos tengan el nombre `recipient-name1` es un problema, es como si todas las personas tuvieran el mismo nombre, es imposible diferenciarlos. Los cambié por `unidad`, `cantidad`, `subtotal`, `impuesto` y `total`.

Cambié `onchange` por `onkeyup` para que se muestre el resultado al presionar teclas, pero eso es a gusto de cada uno.

Se puede usar `getElementById` normalmente o usarlo de manera simplificada con variables propias.

Uno normalmente haría esto: `document.getElementById("elemento").value`, pero debido a que la función tiene un nombre largo, se puede hacer lo siguiente.

```
var d = document
d.o = d.getElementById
var o = (x,y)=>y!=null?d.o(x).value=y:d.o(x).value
```

Luego de esto, usarlo de esta manera.

- En caso de obtener el valor: `o(id)`
- En caso de asignar el valor: `o(id,valor)`

Esta función recibe dos argumentos, uno es el id del elemento y el otro es el valor, que si existe se lo asigna al elemento. Para esto hace uso de `getElementById` encapsulado en una variable con nombre más corto, que es `d.o`, pero en definitiva es lo mismo.

El valor de la unidad, se puede obtener de esta manera, `o("unidad")`, en este caso el tipo de la variable es `String`. Para convertir un `String` a `Number` (de cadena de caracteres a número), se le pone un `+` al principio, en mi caso sería de esta manera `+o("unidad")`, aunque no es necesario porque `JavaScript` al multiplicar dos `String` los pasa a `Number` automáticamente.

Si se quiere mostrar un máximo de *2* decimales, se puede usar `toFixed` para que tenga *2* decimales, y usar el `+` para convertirlo a número, así puede tener *2* como máximo y no siempre *2*. En mi caso lo hago de esta manera: `+y.toFixed(2)`

Con respecto a la lógica que se usa para calcular el *IGV*, yo considero que si el subtotal es *1*, el total tiene que ser *1.18*... En internet encontré **[un enlace](https://www.danielmaza.com/2013/11/calculadora-igv-peru/)** donde lo hacen de esa manera, aunque otros lo podrían hacer diferente.

Código:

```js
var d = document
d.o = d.getElementById
var o = (x,y)=>y!=null?d.o(x).value=+y.toFixed(2):d.o(x).value
function calcular()
{
 var unidad = o("unidad")
 var cantidad = o("cantidad")
 var impuesto = 18/100
 var subtotal = unidad * cantidad
 o("subtotal", subtotal)
 o("impuesto", subtotal * impuesto)
 o("total", subtotal * (1+impuesto))
}
```

```html
<div>Unidad: <input id="unidad" onkeyup="calcular()"></div>
<div>Cantidad: <input id="cantidad" onkeyup="calcular()"></div>
<div>Subtotal: <input id="subtotal" disabled /><div>
<div>IGV (18%): <input id="impuesto" disabled /><div>
<div> Total: <input id="total" disabled /><div>
```

Comment: El código es preciso y conciso, pero habría que explicar al OP algunas partes como por ejemplo por que usa el operador + antes del value o por que no seleccione el elemento con el típico getElementById. Ya que como dice, está comenzando con JavaScript

Comment: @Dev.Joel Gracias, edité la respuesta explicando esos conceptos, espero que sea entendible.

Answer (score 1):

Hice cambios en varias partes, te explico:

1. Tienes identificadores repetidos o algunas etiquetas con 2 id.
2. La forma recomendada de referenciar un un `input` es con `value`.
3. Javascript incluye `isNaN` que valida si una variable `is-Not-a-Number`.
4. Me queda la duda con la lógica que usas, en este caso sumo los valores de impuesto y total, pero veo que tu aplicas una resta.
5. Tu valor cambia porque en ambos input invocas `subtotal(this.value)`, en ocasiones te calcula la cantidad y en otras el valor unitario, en ese caso es mejor referenciar una función de javascript que obtenga valores y ejecute la aritmética.

```js
function subtotal () {
  var precio = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt_campo_1').value);
  var cantidad = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt_campo_2').value);
  var igv = 0.18;
  var sub = precio * cantidad;
  var igvAplicado = sub * igv
  var total = sub + igvAplicado;
  document.getElementById('recipient-name1').value = isNaN(igvAplicado) ? 0 : igvAplicado;
  document.getElementById('spSTotal').innerHTML = isNaN(sub) ? 0 : sub;
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = isNaN(total) ? 0 : total;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-5">
     <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Precio Unit.:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_campo_1" onchange="javascript:subtotal();">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-5">
     <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Cantidad:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_campo_2" onchange="javascript:subtotal();">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Sub Total:</label>
    <label type="text" class="" for="" id="spSTotal"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">IGV (18%):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name1" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Total:</label><br>
    <label type="text" class="" for="" id="spTotal"></label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```